# Dart: HttpException

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I am developing a mobile app communicating with an api and it is working fine. When I tried the app with the public url (https), the http client throws 'HttpException' without any details. The server certificate is valid. Do I need to trust the certificate in the code or any other configuration.
My code is something like this.

```
final response = await http.post(
      Uri.https('dev.company.com', '/api/someController/'),
      headers: _requestHeaders,
      body: _body,
    );
```

Comment: did you try removing the trailing slash?

Comment: yes @MaartenDev I did, but with no luck.

Comment: It looks like your server needs to configure CORS. Google for it.

Comment: @intraector CORS is to make browsers happy. This seems to be an app.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from the Server side.
It was requiring client certificate, and by disabling it. everything worked.